# Some fields get old values in fragment cache in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, fragment-caching

I have a view to show the details of a resource that is saved in the database. Some of the details belong to the Resource model itself, and some details belongs to associated models.

In the view I use fragment caching for the details.

When the user presses a button on the view, a part of the view is replaced by a form, so the user can edit the details witout loading a new page. When the form is opened, the cache is expired (it actually is, I have checked). When the user submits the form (`using :remote => true`), the form is hidden, and the original content is reloaded using jQuery and render partial.

So far everything work just fine. The original content is reloaded correctly with the new values, from code inside `<% cache ... do %>` and `<% end %>`.

The strange thing is when I reload the page, some of the new values are gone. Instead some old values are shown (those that should have been cached after the last submit). And the thing that is even stranger is that some of the values are updated, even if they are in the same new cache file as the wrong values.

As far as I can see, values in associated models are correct, while values in the Resource model are wrong (old). I have wondered if it had something to do with sql caching, but I don't think that's the case, because I think the sql cache should be emptied when reloading the page.

If I open the form and submit again, the data is updated, and everything is fine. That is the data from the last submit is coming into the cache. If I change the data in the form before submitting, it is still the data from the last submit that is included in the cache-file. So it seems that data submitted for the Resource model is delayed by one submit, even if the other fields are updated correctly.

If I turn off caching in development.rb, everything works as expected. All data are updated every time.

I do, by the way, have the same problem on my server.

Anyone that has a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but in the last couple of days I have implemented a cache-key based fragment cache scheme on my own site with some success.

I implemented a get_cache_key function in all my models

```
  def get_cache_key(prefix=nil)
    cache_key = []
    cache_key << prefix if prefix
    cache_key << self

    child_objects.in_sort_order.each do |child_object|
      cache_key << child_object.get_cache_key
    end

    return cache_key.flatten
  end
```

In my views I then used

```
<% cache(@home_page.get_cache_key('some_name_for_fragment')) do %>
...Render View
<% end %>
```

The models now produce a cache key that will invalidate the cache if parent model or any of its children are changed.

The full write up is here, on my website.
[Rails caching strategy using key-based approach](http://mark.stratmann.me/content_items/rails-caching-strategy-using-key-based-approach)

Comment: In addition to not including your 'signature', please also keep in mind that when you link to your own website, you must disclose that it is your website. I have added the required disclosure here for you.

Comment: Thank's for your reply! I haven't had time (nor motivation) to go fully into this before now. Since the cache files actually are deleted, I think your solution won't help. So I tried something else. I hope it works! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the data are cached a bit to soon after they are updated. My solution so far is to drop caching in the view if it is less then two minutes since the resource was updated. The fragment is uncached until someone updates the page a bit later. This is not a very good solution, while each resource (30 resources) on the page must be queried for update time each time the page is viewed.